# split with regex in java

Tags: java, regex

I want to split strings with regex java.
for example:

```
String: (5,4,a)
```

I want to split two String in following:

```
5 
4,a
```

if character is numeric after comma character do split
if character is letter after comma character do not split

I use of

```
[-|,]\\s*[^\\w]
```

but do no right

Comment: Any attempts from your side ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use *positive lookahead* - a request that tells regex engine that a certain character must be there, but should not be consumed as part of the match:

```
"[()]|[,-](?=\\d)"
```

should do the job ([demo on ideone](http://ideone.com/SODZnS)). Above, `(?=\\d)` means "only if followed by a digit", without counting that digit as part of the match.

Answer (score 3):

It is often better to not come up with a complex regex that "does it all". Just split on comma, then look if the last element is a number, if not you can still concatenate the second and thrid field again.

Comment: I do agree, but in this case, the regex would not be that complex though.

Comment: @sp00m yes, but obviously complex enough to start a question on SO. When it comes to regexes I advocate extreme simplicity, because chances are high that next week you simply do not understand the regex you got from that SO guy.

Answer (score 1):

Try this out:

```
    String str = "5,4,c";
    // Just split the string into two parts
    String[] split = str.split(",", 2);

    System.out.println(split[0]);
    System.out.println(split[1]);
```